# How do I get 300% CPU usage? Is top command flawed?

Tags: linux, top

Here's a picture of the `top` command on my VPS.

[image]

As you can see `sqlserver` + `dotnet` are taking near 300% CPU usage. How is that even possible?

Can I trust `top` results from now on? Is this app flawed and buggy?

Answer (score 2):

In top - 100% is the 'full' load of one CPU 'thread' - on a non HT processor, that's one physical core, and on a Hyperthreading capable processor (where you can run 2, or even more threads per physical processor), one of the virtual cores. Your processor are taking about one and half of one processor's 'maximum' performance each, and that shouldn't be an issue as long as your total usage isn't Nx100%.

`htop` tends to show this a little more precisely, with processor load per core graphs, but fundamentally, its working as designed.

Comment: You can also press shift + i to toggle IRIX mode and change this behavior.